# Can someone help explain this python code

Tags: python

This is meant to create a randomized maze but I don't really understand whats happening due to the list comprehensions used could someone explain what is happening. Thanks.

```
from random import shuffle, randrange

def make_maze(w = 20, h = 20):
    vis = [[0] * w + [1] for _ in range(h)] + [[1] * (w + 1)]
    ver = [["|  "] * w + ['|'] for _ in range(h)] + [[]]
    hor = [["+--"] * w + ['+'] for _ in range(h + 1)]

    def walk(x, y):
        vis[y][x] = 1

        d = [(x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1)]
        shuffle(d)
        for (xx, yy) in d:
            if vis[yy][xx]: continue
            if xx == x: hor[max(y, yy)][x] = "+  "
            if yy == y: ver[y][max(x, xx)] = "   "
            walk(xx, yy)

    walk(randrange(w), randrange(h))

    s = ""
    for (a, b) in zip(hor, ver):
        s += ''.join(a + ['\n'] + b + ['\n'])
    return s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(make_maze())
```

Comment: It's not that easy. I would suggest you to go through this code step-by-step. first of all, write `print(vis)`. Then you will what this line will generate. Try to understand the syntax. Go on from there..

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the first line:

```py
vis = [[0] * w + [1] for _ in range(h)] + [[1] * (w + 1)]
```

`[0] * w + [1]` makes a list of length `w` comprised of all zeros and then appends a single 1 at the end. This is one row.

`for _ in range(h)` means it repeats that process `h` times to make `h` rows.

`+ [[1] * (w + 1)]` means it appends another row of length `(w + 1)` comprised of all 1s.

`vis` is basically a grid the same size as the maze to keep track of visited spaces so the random walk (discussed below) doesn't hit the same point twice

---

The other two list comprehensions, `ver` and `hor` work in a similar manner and essentially makes a giant grid with rows as shown below (not a maze yet)

```
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
```

---

Then `walk(x, y)` replaces random walls with spaces.

*i.e. it randomly removes* `--` or `|` *characters from the grid to open up the maze*

additionally, `walk()` recursively calls itself to remove more walls near the wall it removed to create "hallways"

---

Then it just uses the `.join()` function to combine the vertical and horizontal character rows into a single string.